# UITableView/UIScrollView delegate not getting set to nil when ViewController deinits

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using Swift 1.2

I have a UIViewController that is the delegate of a UITableView. When I pop this VC off a NavigationController the UIScrollView inside the UITableView tries to call my VC after it has been released and causes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash.

Why? Shouldn't ARC sort this out?

To fix this I've have to write:

```
deinit {
    self.tableView.delegate = nil
}
```

Annoying. Am I doing something stupid?

Delegate is hooked up in a storyboard, which isn't in any way strange. Can't think of anything that is abnormal about my setup, in fact.

UITableView delegate declaration:

```
// Swift
unowned(unsafe) var delegate: UITableViewDelegate?

// Obj-C
@property(nonatomic, assign) id< UITableViewDelegate > delegate
```

**To add to Alex's correct answer**, this is fixed in iOS 9 apparently:

https://twitter.com/zwaldowski/status/627158943035457536
https://twitter.com/steipete/status/608387828221898754

Comment: Give some context -- the full function, and exact line, in which the crash occurs. Where/Why does the UITableView feel it still has an event to process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all of Apple's frameworks use ARC internally. What you're looking at is probably a result of `UIScollView`/`UITableView` still using manual memory management.

Comment: Hmmmm. I'm stunned that I've never run in to this issue. I've updated my question with what the docs say. Isn't assign pretty much the same as weak? Doesn't up the retain count?

Comment: The difference between `assign` and `weak` is subtle. Pointers with `weak` retain semantics in Objective-C / Swift are zeroing. This means, when the referenced object is deallocated, the pointer changes to 0. On the other hand, `assign`/`unowned(unsafe)` is not zeroing. This means the pointer has the same value as before, but the object it references has been deallocated.

Comment: If you run your app in Instruments with the Zombies gauge, this is really highlighted quite nicely.